# Product finder dropdowns are not reset

Tags: magento-1.9

I have added product finder in the header.

When I search product using product finder then it goes to the finder page

`URL`  http://localhost/staging/amfinder/?find=ask-projector-lamp-c100-any-370901

After that, when I go to the category page then no products are displaying in that category while more than 100 products available in that category.

So how to reset the product finder dropdown when going to any other URL?

Comment: Clear the `cache` and `reindex`

Comment: still, the issue is same.

Comment: If it in live server check your `database` url